# How to find distinct values of string columns in hive?

Tags: arrays, string, hive, distinct

HI I have the below scenario where in i have to find the distinct occurrences of a string in a delimited column. Could you please let me know how to do it.

E.g

```
Table : 
Name String, 
Email String, 
Phone string 
address string 

Name : A 
Email : A@gmail.com##B@gmail.com##A@gmail.com##C@gmail.com 
Phone : 123##456##678 
Address : 87P Plz##96C Blk##87P Plz 

Expected output: 
Name : A 
Email : A@gmail.com##B@gmail.com##C@gmail.com 
Phone : 123##456##678 
Address : 87P Plz##96C Blk
```

Also kindly note that we have a different delimiter `##` in our case as we cannot use `,` as the delimiter

Comment: hi @Dudu Markovitz, Could you kindly explain me what is being replaced in the regexp_replace command?

Comment: strings, surrounded by commas from both sides (or anchored to the start/end of the string), where exists an identical string (again, surrounded by ...) somewhere to the right. https://regex101.com/r/75Ejjm/1

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz - Thank you so much. That solved my problem!